# Translate Breadcrumbs for entire store

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, breadcrumbs

how I can translate "Home" word in breadcrumbs section for entire store, even it I turn on Translation tool for magento this word can't be translated. I use Magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in app/locale/[language]/Mage_Cms.csv

This layout xml adds the home breadcrumb (layout/cms.xml):

```
<action method="addCrumb" translate="crumbinfo.label crumbinfo.title" module="cms">
            <crumbname>Home</crumbname>
            <crumbinfo>
                <label>Home</label>
                <title>Home</title>
                <link>/</link>
            </crumbinfo>
        </action>
```

As you can see there, the module is CMS.

Comment: thank you and on all store? Because this is only for cms

Comment: What do you mean with "on all store"? You should have locale csv file per language you have. Or you want to translate it with the database?

Comment: I have locale, but take a look there are a lot of files, for catalog for checkout, and if I put this "Home","My new text" in your file Mage_Cms.csv this will be translated for cms pages or not, so what we need to do in checkout? or in catalog? or in newsletter manage?

Comment: The translations should be pulled from that module translation file "Mage_Cms.csv". It doesn't matter on what page you are. If you put it here, it should translate on the entire site. Don't forget to clear your cache

Comment: Is there in Mage_CMS.csv and for example in the My account at the adress book section is not translated, how is this?

Comment: so? any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Magento_root/app/locale/en_US/

There you will find a lot of CSV files Search for the Home and replace with the word you want to use.

Comment: you see that text in your csv? :)